# Python3 PKCS7Encoder

Tags: python-3.x, pkcs#7

I try to decrypt and encrypt pycryptodome using PKCS7Encoder

My crypter.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import json
from pkcs7 import PKCS7Encoder

class Crypter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.encoder=PKCS7Encoder()

    def decrypt(self,input,key):
        return self.encoder.decode(AES.new(base64.b64decode(key), AES.MODE_CBC, '\x00'*16).decrypt(base64.b64decode(input)))

    def encrypt(self,input,key):
        padded_data=self.encoder.encode(json.dumps(input))
        return base64.b64encode(AES.new(base64.b64decode(key), AES.MODE_CBC, '\x00'*16).encrypt(padded_data))
```

My pkcs7.py

```
import binascii
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

class PKCS7Encoder(object):
    def __init__(self, k=16):
        self.k = k

    def decode(self, text):
        '''
        Remove the PKCS#7 padding from a text string
        '''
        nl = len(text)
        val = int(binascii.hexlify(text[-1]), 16)
        if val > self.k:
            raise ValueError('Input is not padded or padding is corrupt')

        l = nl - val
        return text[:l]

    def encode(self, text):
        '''
        Pad an input string according to PKCS#7
        '''
        l = len(text)
        output = StringIO()
        val = self.k - (l % self.k)
        for _ in range(val):
            output.write('%02x' % val)
        return text + binascii.unhexlify(output.getvalue())
```

its always return error like this

> return text + binascii.unhexlify(output.getvalue()) TypeError: can
>   only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

i try to change bytes to str is not working, any solution?

Comment: It helps to print the variables values in between to see what they contain. E.g., for me, `binascii.unhexlify(output.getvalue())` evaluated a bytes object like `b'\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r'`. You are trying to concatenate this bytes object to a string (`text`), which is not possible.

Comment: @sammy i just wana def encrypt(self,input,key): that return

Comment: Right, but there you have a line like `self.encoder.encode(json.dumps(input))`, right? And `json.dumps(input)` is a string? Then this won't work, because the `PKCS7Encoder.encode` method doesn't work with strings (this is what I said in my first comment).

Comment: @sammy
means this is a dead end for my project, or is there another way to get it? Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know what the method is supposed to do, so I can't tell. I just pointed out the problem. You should consider debugging your code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @sammy btw with python2 its running well, with change range to xrange

Comment: @sammy and than do this print a.decrypt(anjO9AupBu74vdORIFevgOfmwVvai/puDBqLHx6qLozE0j05m/V9ztNJXC4f7I2yhEH2f7gLWI71tH7gUqnW0G3PMTJc6dD85PhZPfBdYK8Vhp6nBjdyFBkBFwRROyoRUbV3Hy3xVPMRwvQ7n/CC454Y4VhMNX67HZOyiKcYfmQFUVAskp0h4lSDQYyQ1IwtG6aY+opI2HnqbUMpsWy/rTJLsFOp+9mOxTNA8i5+Ue2OUP0NhZFua1Q93yur4FME8rLIV60y93we3bkoUMuuwg==)

Comment: In Python 2, `binascii.unhexlify` returns a string object, as opposed to Python 3.